# Does increase in potential energy of a system cause increase in internal energy of the same system?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

When I increase the potential energy of a system, does that mean that I have also increased the internal energy of the system since I’ve done some work on it although the heat of the system remained unchanged? I'm trying to fill every possible gap in my understanding of internal energy.

Comment: Define your system..

Answer (score 1):

Potential energy is not usually considered part of the internal energy of the material within the system.  It is usually considered a separate part of the total energy E of the system in the more-general form of the first law of thermodynamics, expressed as:
$$\Delta E=\Delta U+\Delta (PE)+\Delta (KE)=Q-W$$